# SP online permission management for teamsite and apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I have one complicated query.

i have big environment of Sharepoint online and with multiple Sharepoint apps and sites created for each and every department and their requirements.

Suppose, User A has access for 2/3 SP teamsites and their applications. another User B has access for some other SP Teamsites.

So i want to make SP page or something, where user will login and he will automatically get the SP TeamSites and Apps in good view, only those which he has access to..

Is it possible in Office 365 SharePoint online platform?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph You will get more idea from reference link. Reference: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can add a content search web part into the homepage, use “ContentClass:STS_Site OR ContentClass:STS_Web” property to display all sites that the current user has permissions. You can also use “STS_List” property to display all lists that the current user has permissions. Check the following article for more information about SharePoint search using ContentClass:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/

1. Edit the page and add a content search web part.
2. Edit the web part, click "Change Query". Click "Switch to Advanced Mode", in the "Query text" section, add the below command:

   ContentClass:STS_Site OR ContentClass:STS_Web OR ContentClass:STS_List
3. Save the page and check the results.